# Why is simple_form populating these select lists with all comment_titles?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, plugins, simple-form

So i have this form for generating comment_titles:

```
<%= simple_form_for @video, :remote => true do |f| %>
    <%= f.input :comment_title_names, :label => false, :placeholder => "Add a Comments Title" %>
    <%= f.button :submit, :value => 'Add', :id => 'add_comment_title' %>
    <div class='hint'>Let your listeners know what comments you want by adding a guiding title for them. Pose a question, ask for feedback, or anything else!</div>
<% end %>
```

And this is the relevant part of my video model that allows comment_titles to be created as a virtual attribute:

```
attr_accessor :comment_title_names
after_save :assign_comment_titles

def assign_comment_titles
  if @comment_title_names
    self.comment_titles << @comment_title_names.map do |title|
      CommentTitle.find_or_create_by_title(title)
    end
  end
end
```

Then this is the form for generating a comment where a user must select the desired comment_title:

```
<%= simple_form_for([@video, @video.comments.new]) do |f| %>
  <%= f.association :comment_title, :label => "Comment Title:", :include_blank => false %>
  <%= f.input :body, :label => false, :placeholder => "Post a comment." %>
  <%= f.button :submit, :value => "Post" %>
<% end %>
```

Now the problem is that the comment_title select lists generated by `<%= f.association :comment_title, :label => "Comment Title:", :include_blank => false %>`  seems to populate each list for each video with ALL of the comment titles that have been added to all videos instead of only populating it with the comment_titles that have been added to that specific video. Why is this and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe you want something like this?

`f.association :comment_title, :collection => @video.comment_titles, ...`

Answer (score 0):

By default simple_form don't use the scope of association. See how it works here: https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/blob/master/lib/simple_form/form_builder.rb#L130

Pass the collection option for the association like this:

```
f.association :comment_title, :collection => @video.comment_titles, ...
```